# Python web scraping with lxml - how to login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I follow [this](https://github.com/kazuar/login_scraper_example/blob/master/login_scraper_example.py) tutorial and I get access to my bitbucket and get all the data but when Im using it to another site that also needed a login. It didnt work.

When I print the content im still stack at the login page. The credentials are correct also token in the site is Im successfully get the value. Bdw the site is made of laravel.

Code in tutorial

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "<USERNAME>"
PASSWORD = "<PASSWORD>"

LOGIN_URL = "https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/"
URL = "https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/repositories"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']/@value")))[0]

    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "username": USERNAME, 
        "password": PASSWORD, 
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": authenticity_token
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    bucket_names = tree.xpath("//div[@class='repo-list--repo']/a/text()")

    print(bucket_names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you considered a simpler and more mature approach of getting the data through the [BitBucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/)? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe the tutorial is ok I can get through the bitbucket but when I tried to use it in another site for example facebook I cant get through